# Function with multiple return parameter

Tags: c#, function

I am new to C#. For a motor driver that we use, I want to see its current and there is a BOOL function in motor driver's guide. But I have no idea how I can use it.

```
VCS_GetCurrentIsAveraged(KeyHandle,NodeId, short* pCurrentIsAveraged,
pErrorCode)
```

for this function KeyHandle and NodeId are parameters and pCurrentIsAveraged and pErrorCode are return parameters.

I have all parameters already in my code except pCurrentIsAveraged, which is what I want to see. So how can I get this value as a return.

```
//Initialize

short* pCurrentIsAveraged;

double current;

current=VCS_GetCurrentIsAveraged(KeyHandle,NodeId,pCurrentIsAveraged,
pErrorCode)
```

Would this work, I want to get current but what should I enter for pCurrentIsAveraged value as return parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: You should consult the documentation for your driver API.

Comment: Also, by the * (asterisk), this smells of C/C++ and not C# indicating a POINTER.  This might indicate the value passed in will be changed by its reference to the object in question.  So the function can return something, yet change the value passed due to its POINTER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the function signature `VCS_GetCurrentIsAveraged(KeyHandle,NodeId, short* pCurrentIsAveraged, pErrorCode)` requires you to use unsafe code, which, if you are new to C#, you should avoid.  That looks like a p/invoke wrapper around a C-style API.

As it stands, you would need to call it like this (from an unsafe block) (`fixing` may not be needed if currentIsAveraged happens to be allocated on the stack):

```
short currentIsAveraged = 0;
double current;
fixed (short* pCurrentIsAveraged = &currentIsAveraged) {
   current = VCS_GetCurrentIsAveraged(KeyHandle,NodeId,pCurrentIsAveraged, pErrorCode);
}
bool isCurrentAveraged = (currentIsAveraged != 0);
```

If you have control of the p/invoke definition of `VCS_GetCurrentIsAveraged`, you could change that signature to use an `ref short pCurrentIsAveraged` rather than `short* pCurrentIsAveraged`.   This would let you use that method like this (without the need for unsafe code):

```
short currentIsAveraged = 0;
double current;
current = VCS_GetCurrentIsAveraged(KeyHandle,NodeId,ref currentIsAveraged, pErrorCode);
bool isCurrentAveraged = (currentIsAveraged != 0);
```

You can optimize the p/invoke signature further by using `[Out]` attribute on that value to tell the marshaller to skip a probably unneeded copy, and you could also convice the compiler to treat it as a `bool` directly rather than going back and forth with a `short`, but that's all advanced stuff.  Check out the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace if you are interested in that.